# Constructor overriding

Tags: ruby, super

I have a class:

```
class One
  def initialize; end
end
```

I need to create a new class with my own constructor like this:

```
class Two < One
  def initialize(some)
    puts some
    super
  end
end

Two.new("thing")
```

but when I launch the code, I got an error:

```
thing
test.rb:10:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`super` in this case (without parentheses) is a special form.  It calls the superclass method with the original params.

Instead try calling

```
super()
```