# Implicit argument passing of super from method defined by define_method() is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9, formbuilder

In "*Agile Web Development with Rails*" (third edition) page 537 - 541 it has "Custom Form Builders" code as follows:

```
  class TaggedBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    # <p> # <label for="product_description">Description</label><br/> # <%= form.text_area 'description' %> #</p>
    def self.create_tagged_field(method_name) 
      define_method(method_name) do |label, *args|
        @template.content_tag("p" , @template.content_tag("label" , label.to_s.humanize, 
        :for => "#{@object_name}_#{label}") + "<br/>" + super)
      end
    end
    field_helpers.each do |name| 
      create_tagged_field(name)
    end 
  end
```

This code doesn't work with Ruby 1.9.1. It returns error as follows:

`implicit argument passing of super from method defined by define_method() is not supported. Specify all arguments explicitly. (ActionView::TemplateError)`

My question is: What should I change in the code to fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `super` above passed all parameters (see this [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570428/constructor-overriding)).

As the error message states, you must here "specify all arguments explicitly". Replace `super` with `super(label, *args)`.

Answer (score 17):

I encountered with this problem in a define_method without arguments

```
define_method :"#{info_type}_info" do

  info = super
  .......

end
```

And still found this problem. I had to explicit put the parenthesis:

```
define_method :"#{info_type}_info" do

  info = super()
  .......

end
```

Comment: that looks like a bug in the ruby parser to me. you might want to submit a report to the ruby core team. not sure if it's something they can fix or not. requiring parens doesn't look like ruby to me. :)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a bug. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570428/constructor-overriding), and [this form thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/146693).